# status bar becomes light icons when google in app purchase shown in compose android

Tags: android, kotlin

White status bar with white icons ,same for the navigation bar.
I tried system ui controller to change colour it didn't work.
is anyone had this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This code disables the default behavior of the system to adjust the layout when the status bar color changes, and then sets the status bar color to dark.

You can call this code when the Google in-app purchase dialog is shown, and then reset the status bar color to light when the dialog is dismissed.

```
// When the Google in-app purchase dialog is shown:
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).run {
isAppearanceLightStatusBars = false
show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
}
```